# Calling the OS Telecom Framework from a Web Browser

Tags: android, browser, telecommunication

I need to develop a videocall application for telemonitoring, where a user in a Web Browser (on a Desktop PC running a Web App) calls a user in an Android App (on a Smartphone/Tablet).

Is it possible to use Android's *Telecom Framework* from a *Web Browser*? I was looking at [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

If it's not possible to do such a thing, I was thinking about using a VideoConference service like [Vidyo](https://vidyo.io) along with [FCM](https://blog.mindorks.com/pushing-notifications-in-android-using-fcm) or GCM, to notify the Android App that it should connect to the Conference Room.
But that seems overly complex for this case of use, so a second question would be: Is there a simpler way to achieve a Web Browser to Android App Videocalling service?

Answer (score 2):

No.  That requires a native app, or requires the web browser to provide access to those APIs.  TO my knowledge, none do.  And if they did, it would not likely be the same API, as they'd want it to work across OSes.

Comment: Thanks. So using GCM/FCM to notify the App would be to correct approach? I realize it's a separate question but still, help would be appreciated.

Comment: On rereading this, I actually realized I may have misunderstood.  Are you looking ot have an app in the web browser of the Android device?  Or are you looking at a native app on Android and a user on a PC somewhere using their web browser to call it?  The first is impossible, the second is possible but the web app wouldn't be interacting with the telecom framework-  the native app would.

Comment: The second case. What would the web app interact with?

Comment: Whatever backend service you have that's talking to the Android device.  I'm assuming you're doing some sort of VoIP call, so you'd be streaming voice to the server, and the server would route it to the other user(s).  There's generally not a direct connection, as devices don't generally allow incoming socket connections.

Comment: Also, please note that the tutorial you're looking at is to create an app that appears for normal phone calls-  if you wanted to replace the built in dialer.  If you're doing your own communication channel you wouldn't necessarily follow it-  for one thing the ANdroid framework wouldn't realize that there's a call and start the dialer.  At least not without additional work (it may be possible to make it do so, I just don't know how offhand).